# Not able to install Mongodb server in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: mongodb

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 from Ubuntu 20.04 and it removed my mongodb server installed
and now if I try to install it shows that there is no package named as mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

Mongodb was dropped from Debian and Ubuntu after 20.04.

The upstream project apparently changed their license, and it is no longer compatible with Debian or Ubuntu.

Reference: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=915537#15

Comment: So is there any other method to use it?

Comment: Of course: Download it directly from Upstream. The project still exists, and they still release software.

Comment: But it shows unmet dependencies when i install it

Comment: Please remember that we are not there, and we cannot see what you are experiencing. Yes, Debian volunteers  and Ubuntu volunteers used to discover and solve those problems before the software reached you. Please open a new question for your dependency problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way at this time is to us the mongo docker.